# Selenium"Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, anaconda

I have an anaconda environment with selenium installed. When I try to run I get this error:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Nick\Desktop\Code\product-scraper\sephora-scraper\scraper.py", line 31, in <module>
    ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
  File "C:\Users\Nick\anaconda3\envs\web-scraper\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\chrome.py", line 34, in install
    driver_path = self._get_driver_path(self.driver)
  File "C:\Users\Nick\anaconda3\envs\web-scraper\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\manager.py", line 21, in _get_driver_path
    driver_version = driver.get_version()
  File "C:\Users\Nick\anaconda3\envs\web-scraper\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\driver.py", line 40, in get_version
    return self.get_latest_release_version()
  File "C:\Users\Nick\anaconda3\envs\web-scraper\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\driver.py", line 63, in get_latest_release_version
    resp = requests.get(f"{self._latest_release_url}_{self.browser_version}")
  File "C:\Users\Nick\anaconda3\envs\web-scraper\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nick\anaconda3\envs\web-scraper\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nick\anaconda3\envs\web-scraper\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request    
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nick\anaconda3\envs\web-scraper\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send       
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nick\anaconda3\envs\web-scraper\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /LATEST_RELEASE_88.0.4324 (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))
```

I'm new to anaconda so I don't know what else to provide. Please leave a comment if I need to anything and I will add it right away. Thanks.

Comment: which OS , which python version are you using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add this path to your environment variable:

- ..\Anaconda3
- ..\Anaconda3\scripts
- ..\Anaconda3\Library\bin

You might need to restart windows after set up environment path

Comment: I added all 3, restarted my pc and I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Could you re-try. I wrong type the last one

Comment: when you put the .. do I need to find the correct path in my system?

Comment: Yeah of course. You must find the correct path the Ananconda is set up in your computer

Comment: For example:  C:\\Ananconda3\